# D3 Json request getting XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, html, xml, http, d3.js

I'm using d3.json() to request a json object and parse/visualize it...

It's being requested from a java servlet doGet function...I know for a fact that my java server is successful sending the json to the browser. However, I'm running into a problem trying to parse the json. d3.json is supposed to do an http get request, but for some reason, it is returning an XML request error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load "http://localhost:8080/cluster". Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Is there some further set up I should know about with d3.json or is it supposed to just work out of the box? Here is my code..

```
    d3.json("http://localhost:8080/cluster", function(json) {       

            //do visualization
            var node = vis.data([json]).selectAll("g.node")
             .data(pack.nodes)
             .enter().append("g")
             .attr("class", function(d) {return d.children ? "node" : "leaf node" ;})
             .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y +")"; });

            node.append("title")
                .text(function(d) { return d.name + (d.children ? "" : ": " + format(d.size)); });



            node.append("circle")
            .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; });

            node.filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }).append("text")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("dy", ".3em")
            .text(function(d) { return d.name.substring(0, d.r / 3); });
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong here? I'm mainly confused because d3.json is supposed to do an HTTP get by default, but its returning an XMLHTTPrequest error...

Comment: It's not related to D3, any XMLHTTPRequest you make to another domain will throw this error if access is not allowed. How are you loading the page containing this code?

Comment: I see...how do I go about allowing cross-orgin resource sharing? Is this something that should be set in the javascript or my jetty server?

Comment: Your server has to set the appropriate HTTP header. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing. But if the server is also serving this page then you should have to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading you HTML file using the file protocol (file:///) then you will run into this issue. Try to load the html file also using localhost, and that should resolve the issue.